# Understanding the output of scipy.optimize.basinhopping

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am using scipy.optimize.basinhopping to minimize a function. Here is what I get:

```
Out[96]: 
                  nfev: 162178
 minimization_failures: 2501
                   fun: 4.4702905615653705
                     x: array([-194.7754468])
               message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
                  njev: 44057
                   nit: 2500
```

However, I have difficulties in understanding the output. What are the meaning of these returned parameters:

- nfev
- minimization_failures
- njev
- nit

I guess nfev = number of function evaluation, and nit should correspond to 'number of iteration'. But why are nit != nfev?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the outputs are documented in [`scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html):

- `nfev` : number of function evaluations
- `njev` : number of Jacobian evaluations
- `nit` : number of iterations of the algorithm

The other options are less well documented, but you can always look at the [Github source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_basinhopping.py) to understand. `minimization_failures` refers to the number of times the local optimizer failed to converge (this might happen if the Monte Carlo step proposes a starting position for the local optimizer that is too far from the local minimum).

`nit`, the number of iterations of the basin-hopping algorithm, is expected to be much less than `nfev`, the number of function evaluations. An iteration corresponds to the following steps:

- propose a new position by displacing randomly around the current position,
- minimize the function (using a local optimizer) to find the basin minimum,
- either accept or reject the new basin.

There will be many function evaluations as part of the local minimization procedure, hence we expect `nfev` to be much bigger than `nit`.