# Interpreting scipy.optimize.basinhopping() return values (nit, nfev, njev) and status messages

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm minimizing a multiple-variable function using `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` and trying to interpret the optimization result. I understand

```
nfev: 747
nit: 100
njev: 747
```

in the lower section of the return value as saying there were 100 basin-hopping (i.e. global) iterations, and there were 747 function and Jacobian evaluations (for local minimizations as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728483/understanding-the-output-of-scipy-optimize-basinhopping)). But what is the meaning of

```
nfev: 47
nit: 39
njev: 47
status: 0
```

in the upper part?

```
minimizer_args = {"args": parameters, "method": "L-BFGS-B", "jac": True, "options": {'disp': False}}
OptimizeResult = optimize.basinhopping(self.func, x0, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_args, disp=True)
print(OptimizeResult)
                        fun: 120760.34909789998
 lowest_optimization_result:       fun: 120760.34909789998
 hess_inv: <5x5 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([-1.087219e-06, -9.192922e-07, -1.440519e-06, -1.775370e-06, -1.944876e-06])
  message: 'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'
     nfev: 47
      nit: 39
     njev: 47
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([  835.797691,  -984.43798 , -2270.562058,  4040.534726, -1323.300916])
                    message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
      minimization_failures: 0
                       nfev: 747
                        nit: 100
                       njev: 747
                    success: True
                          x: array([  835.797691,  -984.43798 , -2270.562058,  4040.534726, -1323.300916])
```

Related to this, I used `disp=True` to display `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` status messages but the same message is repeated at each iteration (the value of the evaluated function remains the same):

```
basinhopping step 0: f 120760
basinhopping step 1: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 2: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 3: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 4: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 5: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 6: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 7: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 8: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 9: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
<snip>
basinhopping step 90: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 91: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 92: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 93: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 94: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 95: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 96: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 97: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 98: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
basinhopping step 99: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760
```

The User Guide pages for [scipy.optimize.basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) and [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) didn't explain this. Thank you for any insight into what these messages mean.

Comment: The [documentation for `basinhopping`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) has "Returns: resOptimizeResult", and that description has a link to OptimizeResult. Did you check out that link?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I checked it out. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer the questions I asked.

Comment: "Number of evaluations of the objective functions and of its Jacobian and Hessian." and "Number of iterations performed by the optimizer." and "Termination status of the optimizer. Its value depends on the underlying solver. Refer to message for details.". What are you missing for your questions to be answered?

Comment: Please read the first two paragraphs of my question. nfev, nit, njev are repeated twice and each time they have a different value. So they can't refer to the same thing.

Comment: Bit of a guess, but given that "Basin-hopping is a two-phase method that combines a global stepping algorithm with local minimization at each step.": the second list is the total number of global steps, the first list is the number of local steps for the best minimum (since it mentions "LbfgsInvHessProduct" there, and you pass "L-BFGS-B" for the local minimizer). The 747 may be overall (global times local), while the 47 may be for the best minimum only.

Comment: Thank you. What you say is very plausible. I need to understand the significance of LbfgsInvHessProduct.

Comment: What I still don't understand is why all the basinhopping step messages look the same as the first one (_basinhopping step 1: f 120760 trial_f 120760 accepted 1  lowest_f 120760_). Shouldn't the numbers change? (See how _f_, _trial_f_, and _lowest_f_ always equal _120760_ and don't change.) Also, occasionally I get **warning: basinhopping: local minimization failure** together with **message: 'ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH'** but it's not clear what needs to be modified.

Comment: Does **message: 'ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH'** mean that the optimization results are invalid? If so, what is it that needs to be modified?